# how to check the username and password before insert in servlet

Tags: servlets

i want to check username and password before inserting details into table. if the username and password matches with the username and password in another table then only allow to insert details.how to do? please provide the code.

I am using net beans 7.0.1 and mysql database.

my code is:-

```
String query1,pass1;

query1 = "select username,password from login";
stmt.executeQuery(query1);


             ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();


             while(rs.next())   
             {
               user1 = rs.getString("username") ;

               pass1 = rs.getString("password");

               if(user1.equals("username") && user1.equals("password"))
               {
                 query = "insert into units (IO_number,Physical_progress,Financial_progress,Final_Completion_Date)values('"+IO_number+"','"+Physical_progress+"','"+Financial_progress+"','"+Final_Completion_Date+"')"; 

                 int i = stmt.executeUpdate(query);

               }
             }
```

Comment: Please avoid duplicates, you already posted this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229732/to-check-username-and-password-in-servlet

Comment: Use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to execute queries .

Comment: This is perfect for an SQL-injection. What should this code do? You are not even running the first query.

Answer (score 0):

you already have the basics of the first query down, but the way it looks now, it's dangerous and a liability because it is vulnerable to SQL injections.

In this example i'll show you how to do querying with preparedstatements (which is way safer) and how you can check if any users exist for the given combination of username and password)

```
try {
      //this portion assumes you know how to set up a connection to your database
      //provider
      conn = getConnection();
      String query = "select count(*) from tableName where username = ? and password = ?";
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      pstmt.setString(1, username); //puts the username at the position of the first question mark
      pstmt.setString(2, password); //and the password at the position of the second one.
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      if (rs.next()) {
        int numberOfRows = rs.getInt(1);
        System.out.println("numberOfRows= " + numberOfRows);
        if(numberOfRows == 0)
        {
          System.out.println("No user found for this username and password");
        }
        else
        {
          //you could set a flag here to indicate that you found a username and password
        } 
      } else {
        System.out.println("error: could not get the record counts");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

For further reading, i suggest you look at [Oracle's own documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: No, your question is literally "how to check the username and password before insert in servlet", so i'm showing you exactly how to do that.

Comment: But then i suppose what you want is to merge two tables based on redundant fields in those tables?

Comment: it means before inserting value in my database how can i check the username and password...so that to find whether it is valid or not...

Comment: how to check the username and password before inserting record in database....please sir help me....

Comment: how does my example *not* do that?
I think you don't get what usernames and passwords are for.
If you want to match users between two different tables (which appears to be what you want to do after all), you could just do with the user's numeric ID, or just the username if you made sure it always has a unique value